# classic category learning tasks with data

Tags: learning, experimental-psychology, data

I need a list of classic categorization tasks (with available human/animal data) to use as a benchmark for a model.

I am interested in tasks that can be used to validate/invalidate a model of category learning

Here are some sample tasks that are used for model valuation:

- the 5-4 task
- Shepard, Hovland, & Jenkins, 1961
- Medin and Schwanenflugel, 1981
- Martin & Carmazza, 1980

any others?

#### References

- Martin, R.C. & Caramazza, A. (1980). Classification in well-defined and ill-defined categories: Evidence for common processing strategies.. Journal of Experimental Psychology: General, 109, 320.
- Medin, D.L. & Schwanenflugel, P.J. (1981). Linear separability in classification learning.. Journal of Experimental Psychology: Human Learning and Memory, 7, 355.
- Shepard, R.N., Hovland, C.I. & Jenkins, H.M. (1961). Learning and memorization of classifications. Psychological Monographs: General and Applied, 75, 1-42.

Comment: can you provide more detailed citations on the 'tasks like' section. Also, what kind of answer do you expect? Do you want it to point to a survey/meta-analysis, or do you want answers to start listing specific studies? If the first is the case, then clarify your question as such and add the [tag:reference-request] tag. If the latter is the case, then flag your question for moderator attention so they can make it a community-wiki big-list. Finally, the more time you invest into carefully forming and communicating your question, the more likely others are to invest time in providing good answers